# Изображение на всю высоту в правом блоке

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста приклеить изображение в правый блок на всю высоту экрана, с нулевыми отступами, как на изображении. Возможно без использование bootstrap реализовать?
[image: Изображение]

Comment: может height: 100%?

Comment: С какими свойствами следует обернуть блок с изображением чтобы оно отображалось по правому краю с 100% height?

Comment: пользуй flexbox'ы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так ..

Я до конца не доделал, не стал наполнять до конца

В общем использовалась портретное изображение

> смотреть на полный экран

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #4D515E;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.items {
  width: 768px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.item_centered {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item_centered">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
      </p>
      <h2>
        become a member
      </h2>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto nesciunt neque accusamus!
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://resi.ze-robot.com/dl/ci/city-768%C3%971024.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сейчас буду разбираться в вашем решении задачи.

Comment: @Кирилл если устроило - то палец вверх и отметь решением

Comment: Выложил не совсем корректный скрин макета, изображение исправил, а именно класс items должен быть на всю ширину экрана. Сейчас сижу пытаюсь изменить ваш код чтобы отображалось как на изображении.

Comment: @Кирилл это не сложно же - items это родитель для item которых два

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.box {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.box-inner {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem calc(30% + 2rem) 2rem 2rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.box-inner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506964110246-f73975e2b20a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, enim accusantium hic quae alias iusto dolorum vel quia eum repellendus quidem ex non, facere, culpa illum aliquid temporibus, voluptate! Porro.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, enim accusantium hic quae alias iusto dolorum vel quia eum repellendus quidem ex non, facere, culpa illum aliquid temporibus, voluptate! Porro.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

если изображение написано в html через тэг img - даёте ему класс, в css width и height 100%. Изображение должно быть дочерним элементом блока. Покажите свой код, так будет понятнее.

Например есть обертка для двух блоков. 
Один див с контентом, другой с изображением.

обертке можете задать display: flex; Тогда элементы будут располагаться в линию.
Высоту блоков можно регулировать так же высотой обертки, а блокам дать height: 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант с `absolute`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}



.box {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.box-thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
}

.box-thumb>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-body">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, enim accusantium hic quae alias iusto dolorum vel quia eum repellendus quidem ex non, facere, culpa illum aliquid temporibus, voluptate! Porro.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-thumb">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506964110246-f73975e2b20a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```